# Draw parallel measurement notation lines using d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, math, svg

I am trying to draw parallel lines to a `polyline` so that they will look like this:

[image]

I have all the points needed to draw polyline but using those points to draw individual lines and translating them shifts line slightly on both axis and those lines are also connected to each other. I want them exactly as shown in the above image.

I am using this code:

```
points = [[83.5,144],[172.5,71],[281.5,133],[385.5,77],[437.5,152]];

for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {        
    if (i <= this.points.length - 2) {
        g.append('line')
            .attr('class', "notationLine")
            .attr("x1", points[i][0])
            .attr("y1", points[i][1])
            .attr("x2", points[i+1][0])
            .attr("y2", points[i+1][1])
            .attr("marker-end", "url(#arrow)")
            .attr("marker-start", "url(#arrowStart)")
            .attr('stroke', '#53DBF3')
            .attr('stroke-width', 1)
            .attr("transform", "translate(-10, -20)");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need for this is a bit of trigonometry.

For instance, given the distance you set...

```
const distance = 15;
```

... you calculate the angle between the two points with [`Math.atan2`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2) and multiply its sine or cosine by the distance you want, sine for `x` positions and cosine for `y` positions:

```
distance * Math.sin(Math.atan(y, x))//for x
distance * Math.cos(Math.atan(y, x))//for y
```

Here is the demo with your data points:

```js
const points = [
  [83.5, 144],
  [172.5, 71],
  [281.5, 133],
  [385.5, 77],
  [437.5, 152]
];

const distance = 15;

const svg = d3.select("svg");

const polyline = svg.append("polyline")
  .attr("points", points.join(" "));

const lines = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.pairs(points))
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr("x1", d => d[0][0] - (distance * Math.sin(Math.atan2(d[0][1] - d[1][1], d[0][0] - d[1][0]))))
  .attr("x2", d => d[1][0] - (distance * Math.sin(Math.atan2(d[0][1] - d[1][1], d[0][0] - d[1][0]))))
  .attr("y1", d => d[0][1] + (distance * Math.cos(Math.atan2(d[0][1] - d[1][1], d[0][0] - d[1][0]))))
  .attr("y2", d => d[1][1] + (distance * Math.cos(Math.atan2(d[0][1] - d[1][1], d[0][0] - d[1][0]))))
```

```css
polyline {
  fill: none;
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

line {
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="200"></svg>
```